# Client to client Communication Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8

I want to make simple game for 2 players in Windows 8.

Is possible to send data from first to second person?

What is the best way to do this?

1) Push notification?

2) Refreshing data from server every 5 seconds?

Comment: client to client with no server == P2P, check this out: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/how-can-i-make-a-peer-to-peer-multiplayer-game

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that by Windows 8 you mean a Windows Store app/game or is Windows desktop game OK?